# PAM USB as two factor authenticator

Tags: pam

Can pamusb be used as two factor authentication? Meaning to require **both** a password and a token to login?

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like it can](https://wiki.debian.org/pamusb#Additional_Mode). "Additional mode" requires password and USB.